# Google docs api file view and download

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api

Has anyone had any luck with the downloading of files using the google docs api?

I've been struggling for weeks now to get this working with no success.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#downloading_documents_and_files

I can get the list of files successfully and display within my web page. However what i want to do next is allow the user to click on a file link which will then open it up in a google docs viewer allowing them to then view and edit that file.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using the newer Google Drive API which is easier to use, supports multiple programming languages and has documentation for each method, including downloading files:

https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-downloads

Comment: Thanks. I do agree that the google drive api is easier to use. However, the problem with that is it doesnt allow you to list all  files..  The Drive API grants access only to two classes of files:

    Files that a user has created with a given Drive app and 
    Files that a user opens with a given Drive app.....i'm integrating google api into my website and need to list all files for a user, not just ones loaded through the website if that makes sense..google docs api has no such restriction

Comment: If you request the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive scope you have access to all files: https://developers.google.com/drive/scopes